# AES Decrypt a file in NodeJs

Tags: java, node.js, encryption

I have a JAVA code that does the AES encryption of excel file on the Windows Operating System. I want to decrypt the same file on the MacOs Operating System using NodeJS. I've written a decrypt function in NodeJs which is giving me the following error

`error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt`

Here is the JAVA Code

```
import java.security.Key;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class fileEncrypter {
   try {
     final SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec("1234".getBytes(), "AES");
     final Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
     final BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(name));
     final BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(name2));
     instance.init(1, key);
     final byte[] b = new byte[4096];
     for (int i = bufferedInputStream.read(b); i > -1; i = bufferedInputStream.read(b)) {
        final byte[] update = instance.update(b, 0, I);
        bufferedOutputStream.write(update, 0, update.length);
     }
     bufferedInputStream.close();
     final byte[] doFinal = instance.doFinal();
     bufferedOutputStream.write(doFinal, 0, doFinal.length);
     bufferedOutputStream.flush();
     bufferedOutputStream.close();
     return "success";
   } catch(Exception obj) {
     System.err.println("Exception occured while encryption:" + obj);
     obj.printStackTrace();
     return obj.toString();
   }
}
```

Here is the NodeJs code to decrypt

```
function Decrypt_AES() {

const ALGORITHM = 'aes-128-ecb';
const ENCRYPTION_KEY = "1234";

var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(ALGORITHM, ENCRYPTION_KEY);
decipher.setAutoPadding(true);
var input = fs.createReadStream('test.enc');
var output = fs.createWriteStream('test_copy.xls');

input.pipe(decipher).pipe(output);

output.on('finish', function () {
    console.log('Encrypted file written to disk!');
});
output.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

}

Comment: I tried with `decipher.setAutoPadding(false);` and the error is gone. But the file is not properly decrypted, I am not able to open the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this problem with the help of [Terry Lennox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7237224/terry-lennox). A big thanks to him first.

First Error:

`error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt`

This was a padding issue,  By default, nodeJs uses PKCS padding so I had to set auto padding to false by using `decipher.setAutoPadding(false);`

This solved the first error

Secondly, I was using `crypto.createDecipher(ALGORITHM, ENCRYPTION_KEY)` which processes the key before using it. To solve this I changed the function to 
`crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGORITHM, ENCRYPTION_KEY, null)`

This was giving me error as we cannot pass `null` in place of IV value.

Since ECB does not require any IV, and we cannot pass null in place of IV I had to set my IV value to this `Buffer.alloc(0)`

This is the code that worked for me

```
function Decrypt_AES() {

    const ALGORITHM = 'aes-128-ecb';
    const key = "1234";
    const ENCRYPTION_KEY = key;

    var IV = Buffer.alloc(0);
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGORITHM, ENCRYPTION_KEY, IV);
    decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
    var input = fs.createReadStream('test.enc');
    var output = fs.createWriteStream('test_copy.xls');

    input.pipe(decipher).pipe(output);

    output.on('finish', function () {
        console.log('Decrypted file written to disk!');
    });
    output.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log(e);
     });
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I've created some examples in both Java and Node.js that will encrypt and decrypt files. The code will be compatible as long as the same key and IV values are used, that is to say the Node code will decrypt the output from the Java and vice-versa.

Now I'm using text files as input here, but you can use any file type as input.

I've updated to use 128-bit AES in ECB mode.

The Key cannot be "1234" since it must be 128-bits long, so I've used the key given below (16 bytes / 128 bits).

**Java**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class fileEncrypter {

  private static final String key = "0123456789ABDCEF";

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      encryptFile(key, "java-input.txt", "java-output.txt");
      decryptFile(key, "java-output.txt", "java-decrypted.txt");
  }

  public static void encryptFile(String secret, String inputFile, String outputFile) 
  {
      try 
      {
          Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
          cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "AES"));

          byte[] inputData = readFile(inputFile);
          byte[] outputData = cipher.doFinal(inputData);
          writeToFile(outputFile, outputData);  
      } 
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
          System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
      }
  }

  public static void decryptFile(String secret, String inputFile, String outputFile) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "AES"));

            byte[] inputData = readFile(inputFile);
            byte[] outputData = cipher.doFinal(inputData);
            writeToFile(outputFile, outputData);  
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    private static byte[] readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        byte[] data = new byte[(int) new File(fileName).length()];
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        dis.readFully(data);
        dis.close();
        return data;
    }

    private static void writeToFile(String fileName, byte[] data) throws IOException {
        final BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        bufferedOutputStream.write(data, 0, data.length);
        bufferedOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

**Node.js**

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const Algorithm = "aes-128-ecb";
const fs = require("fs");

function encryptFile(key, inputFile, outputFile) {
    const inputData = fs.readFileSync(inputFile);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(Algorithm, key, Buffer.alloc(0));
    const output = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(inputData) , cipher.final()]);
    fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, output);
}

function decryptFile(key, inputFile, outputFile) {
    const inputData = fs.readFileSync(inputFile);
    const cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(Algorithm, key, Buffer.alloc(0));
    const output = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(inputData) , cipher.final()]);
    fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, output);
}

const KEY = Buffer.from("0123456789ABDCEF", "utf8");

encryptFile(KEY, "node-input.txt", "node-output.txt");
decryptFile(KEY, "node-output.txt", "node-decrypted.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is different. I have zero control over JAVA code, I only have its encrypt function available for reference, All I want is to create the same encrypt function in NodeJS, I am using the same key specified in JAVA code I've given above with aes-128-ecb algorithm. 

To check if my encrypt function is correct, I have to write a decrypt function that decrypts the file encrypted by JAVA code. I am not getting desired output from my nodejs decrypt function.

Is it because I am using the key as a string in nodejs while in java it is a byte array?

Comment: Ah yes, I understand. Yes, the problem will be that the crypto.createDecipher function processed the encryption key before using it to encypt the data. It derives keys using the OpenSSL function EVP_BytesToKey with the digest algorithm set to MD5, one iteration, and no salt. See https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password_options. Therefore the keys will likely not be the same. I would suggest you use https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options, with IV set to null (since you're using ECB mode).

Comment: So, the problem is in the key and not the padding. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I can certainly try! I'll see if I can match the same type of encryption from Java and Node.js..

Comment: Thanks, btw I tried this `crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGORITHM, ENCRYPTION_KEY, null)` but it says `IV must be a buffer` I think I can't pass null as an IV

Comment: You should be able to pass null as the IV as long as the algorithm doesn't require one, ECB mode (Algorithm = "aes-128-ecb") should not require an IV.

Comment: I've updated both the Java and Node.js examples to reflect our discussion. In both cases we're using 128-bit AES with ECB mode. So they should produce the same output.

Comment: null is not allowerd, IV value must be a string or a buffer, I did this `var IV = Buffer.alloc(0);`